# How can I implement activities into my game?

Tags: batch-file

I am currently making my own game and want to implement activities into it.

If I do the `:a_activity`, *(just to test for now)*, it goes to the `:continue` label, and under the options like `Age` and stuff that it displays that activity I just did. However, if I then do `:b_activity`, it displays the previous activity instead.

Here's the code:

```bash
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
title xinsLife
goto main

:echo-align <align> <text>
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
(set^ tmp=%~2)
if defined tmp (
    set "len=1"
    for %%p in (4096 2048 1024 512 256 128 64 32 16 8 4 2 1) do (
        if "!tmp:~%%p,1!" neq "" (
            set /a "len+=%%p"
            set "tmp=!tmp:~%%p!"
        )
    )
) else (
    set len=0
)
    
for /f "skip=4 tokens=2 delims=:" %%i in ('mode con') do (
    set /a cols=%%i
    goto loop_end
)

:loop_end
if /i "%1" equ "center" (
    set /a offsetnum=^(%cols% / 2^) - ^(%len% / 2^)
    set "offset="
    for /l %%i in (1 1 !offsetnum!) do set "offset=!offset! "
) else if /i "%1" equ "right" (
    set /a offsetnum=^(%cols% - %len%^)
    set "offset="
    for /l %%i in (1 1 !offsetnum!) do set "offset=!offset! "
)
echo %offset%%~2
endlocal
exit /b


:main
cls
title xinsLife
call :echo-align center "xinsLife"
call :echo-align center "New Life"
call :echo-align center "Info"
call :echo-align center "Load Save"
call :echo-align center "End Game"
choice /C:1234
if "%errorlevel%" equ "255" goto main
if "%errorlevel%" equ "4" exit
if "%errorlevel%" equ "3" goto loadsave
if "%errorlevel%" equ "2" goto info
if "%errorlevel%" equ "1" goto newlife
if "%errorlevel%" equ "0" goto main

:newlife
cls
title New Life
goto newlifeCN

:loadsave
cls
echo What name was your character?
set /p charname=
echo Loading %charname%.savefile!
< %charname%.savefile (
    set /p charactername=
    set /p chosecountry=
    set /p charage=
)
timeout /t 3 /nobreak > nul
echo Loaded!
echo Press any key to continue
pause>nul
goto continue

:newlifeCN
echo Name of your character:
set /P nameofcharacter=
echo Your name is %nameofcharacter%. Correct?
choice /C:YN
if "%errorlevel%" equ Y goto setvar1
if "%errorlevel%" equ N goto newlifeCN

:setvar1
set "charactername=%nameofcharacter%"
goto countrychoosing

:countrychoosing
cls
title New Life -- Country choosing
echo.
echo Choose your country:
call :echo-align center "United States"
call :echo-align center "United Kingdom"
call :echo-align center "China"
call :echo-align center "India"
call :echo-align center "More countries to come soon!"
set /p choosecountry=
If "%choosecountry%" == "1" (
    goto unitedstates
)

If "%choosecountry%" == "2" (
    goto unitedkingdom
)   

If "%choosecountry%" == "3" (
    goto china
)

If "%choosecountry%" == "4" (
    goto india
)

:india
Set "chosecountry=India"
goto savesettings

:china
Set "chosecountry=China"
goto savesettings

:unitedkingdom
Set "chosecountry=UK"
goto savesettings

:unitedstates
Set "chosecountry=US"
goto savesettings

:savesettings
echo You chose the country "%chosecountry%". Do you want to create a save file?
choice /C:YN
if "%errorlevel%" equ "255" goto savesettings
if "%errorlevel%" equ "2" goto continuetest
if "%errorlevel%" equ "1" goto createsavefile

:createsavefile
cls
set "charage=0"
echo Your save file will be called: %charactername%.savefile
(
    echo %charactername%
    echo %chosecountry%
    echo %charage%
)>%charactername%.savefile
timeout /t 3 /nobreak > nul
echo Saved!
echo Press any key to continue
pause > nul
goto continue

:continue
title Your LIFE - %charactername% - %charage% years old
cls
echo My name is %charactername%. I was a unplanned child.
echo I was born at July 29th.
if "%charage%" == "85" goto death
echo I am %charage% years old.
echo.
echo Options:
echo Age (+)
echo Activities
echo Surrender
echo Save
echo Quit
choice /C:12345
if "%errorlevel%" equ "255" goto continue
if "%errorlevel%" equ "5" exit
if "%errorlevel%" equ "4" goto save
if "%errorlevel%" equ "3" goto surrender
if "%errorlevel%" equ "2" goto the_activities
if "%errorlevel%" equ "1" goto age

:age
cls
set /a charage=%charage% + 1
goto continue

:death
cls
color 40
echo.
echo You died at %charage% years old.
echo Reason: Old Age (natural death)
echo Press a key to start a new life.
pause > nul
echo Feature not implemented yet.
pause > nul
exit

:the_activities
cls
title Activities - %charactername%
echo.
echo.
echo.
call :echo-align center "Activities"
call :echo-align center "[1] Take a walk"
call :echo-align center "[2] Meditate"
call :echo-align center "[3] Sleep"
call :echo-align center "[4] Sing a song"
call :echo-align center "[5] Dance"
call :echo-align center "[6] Eat"
call :echo-align center "[7] Drink"
call :echo-align center "[8] Hike"
call :echo-align center "[9] Play football"
choice /c 123456789
if "%errorlevel%" equ "255" goto activities
if "%errorlevel%" equ "9" goto j_activity
if "%errorlevel%" equ "8" goto i_activity
if "%errorlevel%" equ "7" goto g_activity
if "%errorlevel%" equ "6" goto f_activity
if "%errorlevel%" equ "5" goto e_activity
if "%errorlevel%" equ "4" goto d_activity
if "%errorlevel%" equ "3" goto c_activity
if "%errorlevel%" equ "2" goto b_activity
if "%errorlevel%" equ "1" goto a_activity
if "%errorlevel%" equ "0" goto the_activities
:a_activity
echo take a walk
pause>nul
goto the_activities

:b_activity
echo meditate
pause>nul
goto the_activities

:c_activity
echo sleep
pause>nul
goto the_activities

:d_activity
echo sing a song
pause>nul
goto the_activities

:e_activity
echo dance
pause>nul
goto the_activities

:f_activity
echo eat
pause>nul
goto the_activities

:g_activity
echo drink
pause>nul
goto the_activities

:h_activity
echo bike
pause>nul
goto the_activities

:i_activity
echo hike
pause>nul
goto the_activities

:j_activity
echo play football
pause>nul
goto the_activities

:save
cls
title Save Life
set "characterage=%charage%"
echo %charactername% > %charactername%.savefile
echo %chosecountry% >> %charactername%.savefile
echo %charage% >> %charactername%.savefile
timeout /t 3 /nobreak > nul
echo Saved
echo Do you want to continue with your life
choice /c:YN
if "%errorlevel%" equ "255" goto save
if "%errorlevel%" equ "N" exit
if "%errorlevel%" equ "Y" goto continue1
if "%errorlevel%" equ "0" goto save

:a_activity
echo take a walk
pause>nul
goto activities

:b_activity
echo meditate
pause>nul
goto activities

:c_activity
echo sleep
pause>nul
goto activities

:d_activity
echo sing a song
pause>nul
goto activities

:e_activity
echo dance
pause>nul
goto activities

:f_activity
echo eat
pause>nul
goto activities

:g_activity
echo drink
pause>nul
goto activities

:h_activity
echo bike
pause>nul
goto activities

:i_activity
echo hike
pause>nul
goto activities

:j_activity
echo play football
pause>nul
goto activities
```

*(The activities like `:a_activity` or `:h_activity` are just tests for now)*